# Does Python logging write to stdout or stderr by default?

Tags: python

The [logging docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) don't mention what the default logger obtained from [`basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) writes to: stdout or stderr.

What is the default behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If no `filename` argument is passed to [logging.basicconfig](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) it will configure a `StreamHandler`.  If a `stream` argument is passed to `logging.basicconfig` it will pass this on to `StreamHandler` otherwise `StreamHandler` defaults to using `sys.stderr` as can be seen from the [StreamHandler docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler)

> class logging.StreamHandler(stream=None)
>
> Returns a new instance of the StreamHandler class. If stream is specified, the instance will use it for logging output; otherwise, sys.stderr will be used.

and the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2bfc2dc214445550521074f428245b502d215eac/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L827):

```
class StreamHandler(Handler):
    """
    A handler class which writes logging records, appropriately formatted,
    to a stream. Note that this class does not close the stream, as
    sys.stdout or sys.stderr may be used.
    """

    def __init__(self, stream=None):
        """
        Initialize the handler.
        If stream is not specified, sys.stderr is used.
        """
        Handler.__init__(self)
        if stream is None:
            stream = sys.stderr
        self.stream = stream
```

Answer (score 9):

Apparently the default is stderr.

A quick check: Using a minimal example

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger.info("test")
```

and running it with `python test.py 1> /tmp/log_stdout 2> /tmp/log_stderr` results in an empty stdout file, but a non-empty stderr file.