# Why Python logging writes to stderr by default?

Tags: python, logging, default, stderr

Related to [Does Python logging write to stdout or stderr by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56496458/5492820) but I want to know **WHY** it defaults to `stderr` instead **WHAT** is the default.

For me it isn't really obvious why `stderr` is the default. I noticed that something is wrong when I run `python script.py | tee out.log` and ended up with empty log file. Now I know that It can be solved by either `python script.py 2>&1 | tee out.log` or using `stream` parameter:

```py
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout)
```

After that event it seems reasonable to me to change default `stream` to `stdout` in each script to avoid being surprised again. Is that a good practice? Will I miss something?

Comment: If I am to hazard a guess, it is because logging is not considered to be the output of the program, but kind of like "running commentary" the program is doing. Just like a director's commentary is not merged into the default audio stream on a DVD, logging too is kept separate from stdout so that it does not interfere with the program's output; if you wish to print something to stdout, print it, don't log it. However, this sort of a question can only authoritatively be answered by the people who implemented it in the first place, so it's not a great fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Amadan I find your comment as most informative and if it was an actual answer I would've accepted it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably don't want to change the default to stdout.
The reason for that is stderr is meant to be an output for all messages that are just some internal and/or debugging program information like logs and errors, rather than actual output, the result of the program.

Answer (score 4):

A computer program basically takes data as input and create data as output.
While a program is running, one may be informed of its actions thanks to a monitoring, without altering its output data. To do so, computer programs traditionally have two outputs, one standard output for data and another one for monitoring (logging and errors): stderr.

This is especially useful when your program is pipeable: you wouldn't have error messages in-between video pixels, for example, because it would break your data.