# Why the stream is always stderr, when docker/containerd writes *.json.log

Tags: docker, kubernetes, logging, containerd

when i use docker as CRI:

```
{"log":"I0421 14:23:18.944348       1 node.go:172] Successfully retrieved node IP: 192.168.49.2\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2023-04-21T14:23:18.944635198Z"}
{"log":"I0421 14:23:18.944724       1 server_others.go:142] kube-proxy node IP is an IPv4 address (192.168.49.2), assume IPv4 operation\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2023-04-21T14:23:18.944838628Z"}
{"log":"W0421 14:23:19.008388       1 server_others.go:578] Unknown proxy mode \"\", assuming iptables proxy\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2023-04-21T14:23:19.008544314Z"}
{"log":"I0421 14:23:19.008581       1 server_others.go:185] Using iptables Proxier.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2023-04-21T14:23:19.008653777Z"}
{"log":"I0421 14:23:19.008904       1 server.go:650] Version: v1.20.0\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2023-04-21T14:23:19.008963124Z"}
{"log":"I0421 14:23:19.009762       1 config.go:315] Starting service config controller\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2023-04-21T14:23:19.009986673Z"}
{"log":"I0421 14:23:19.009867       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for service config\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2023-04-21T14:23:19.009999075Z"}
{"log":"I0421 14:23:19.009973       1 config.go:224] Starting endpoint slice config controller\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2023-04-21T14:23:19.010041688Z"}
{"log":"I0421 14:23:19.009979       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for endpoint slice config\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2023-04-21T14:23:19.01004961Z"}
{"log":"I0421 14:23:19.110110       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for endpoint slice config \n","stream":"stderr","time":"2023-04-21T14:23:19.110273306Z"}
{"log":"I0421 14:23:19.110120       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for service config \n","stream":"stderr","time":"2023-04-21T14:23:19.110525274Z"}
```

And

when i use containerd as CRI:

```
2022-07-19T11:13:32.228206987+08:00 stderr F I0719 11:13:32.228176       1 conntrack.go:100] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max' to 524288
2022-07-19T11:13:32.228229469+08:00 stderr F I0719 11:13:32.228203       1 conntrack.go:52] Setting nf_conntrack_max to 524288
2022-07-19T11:13:32.228460095+08:00 stderr F I0719 11:13:32.228431       1 conntrack.go:83] Setting conntrack hashsize to 131072
2022-07-19T11:13:32.237601129+08:00 stderr F I0719 11:13:32.237568       1 conntrack.go:100] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established' to 86400
2022-07-19T11:13:32.237638594+08:00 stderr F I0719 11:13:32.237613       1 conntrack.go:100] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait' to 300
2022-07-19T11:13:32.237787689+08:00 stderr F I0719 11:13:32.237756       1 config.go:315] Starting service config controller
```

Any body know why the stream of log file is always stderr?

i expect that info messages is writing to stdout and err messages is writing to stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STDOUT is usually a command’s normal output, and STDERR is typically used to output error messages. By default, docker/container logs show the command’s STDOUT and STDERR. This information that is logged and the format of the log depends almost entirely on the container’s endpoint command. ***When you use docker/ container as CRI to write the logs in Json it shows the default as STDERR and this needs to be parsed before moving to the logging agent.***

Refer to this [GIT LINK](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/522) by stevenAcoffman for more information and here they used fluentbit as log parser.

You can also use [sematext](https://sematext.com/docs/logagent/installation-docker/#kubernetes-with-containerd-and-ibm-cloud) as a Log agent which supports CRI-O log format as well and install its [Plugin](https://sematext.com/docs/logagent/input-filter-containerd/) to parse the logs.

> By default, Docker captures the standard output (and standard error)
> of all your containers, and writes them in files using the JSON
> format. The JSON format annotates each line with its origin (stdout or
> stderr) and its timestamp. Each log file contains information about
> only one container. `{"log":"Log line is here\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-01-01T11:11:11.111111111Z"}`

Along with the above, you need to install [JSON Logging file driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
When I look at the source code for containerd, it defines two logger io for container:

`
  wc := cioutil.NewSerialWriteCloser(f)
  stdout, stdoutCh = cio.NewCRILogger(logPath, wc, cio.Stdout, c.config.MaxContainerLogLineSize)
  // Only redirect stderr when there is no tty.
  if !tty {
   stderr, stderrCh = cio.NewCRILogger(logPath, wc, cio.Stderr, c.config.MaxContainerLogLineSize)
  }
`

so i'm confused is why the stream is always stderr? Which code controls this result?
Do you know the answers? Thanks again.

Comment: I have edited the answer, can you try using the JSON Logging file driver.

Comment: As per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58971395/19230181) by Tim :  A computer program basically takes data as input and create data as output. While a program is running, one may be informed of its actions thanks to a monitoring, without altering its output data. To do so, computer programs traditionally have two outputs, one standard output for data and another one for monitoring (logging and errors): stderr. Thats the reason the stream is always stderr.

Comment: Sorry, i already comments `thanks a lot` eight hours ago, i do not know why the comments is disappear.
Thanks again, the answer is very clear, got it.